# Can I have multiple type of exception within the same catch?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, can I have multiple type of exception within the same catch?
I just want to if its possible to do something like this, I appreciate any help

```
try
{
}
catch (ArgumentException || FormatException x)
{
  // do something....
}
catch(Exception x)
{
  throw;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey can you can try this.

```
try
{
  // do something....
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 if(ex is ArgumentException || ex is FormatException)
   {
      //do something
   }
   else
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

Or even simpler

```
try {
  // do somthing.
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
{
    //do something
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked

Answer (score 6):

In C# 7.0 and later,  you can do this (Pattern Matching):

```
try
{
    // code that may throw an exception
    int x = int.Parse("abc");
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
{
    // code to handle FormatException and OverflowException
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

[Source](https://tutorials.eu/how-to-catch-multiple-exceptions-c-sharp/#:%7E:text=Catching%20multiple%20exceptions%20in%20C%23,on%20the%20same%20try%20block.)

Comment: Or even `catch (Exception ex) when (ex is FormatException or OverflowException)`